# AWS Service role vs Service link role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to understand the service link role. I understand service role is some thing, when attached to a service, will be able to perform things mentioned in the policy associated with the service role. What is service link role. I am having hard time understanding the thin line between these two. The AWS documentation is good, but I am not understanding the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Service-linked roles are pre-defined roles that are assignable to only a specific service, and cannot be modified. I think of them as somewhat protected and hardcoded roles with sensible defaults.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html

> **AWS service role**
>
> A service role is an IAM role that a service assumes to perform actions on your behalf. An IAM administrator can create, modify, and delete a service role from within IAM.

and

> **AWS service-linked role**
>
> A service-linked role is a type of service role that is linked to an AWS service. The service can assume the role to perform an action on your behalf. Service-linked roles appear in your AWS account and are owned by the service. An IAM administrator can view, but not edit the permissions for service-linked roles.

Answer (score 0):

Service Linked roles and Service roles are not the same thing

Service linked roles

1. A service-linked role is a unique type of IAM role that is linked directly to an AWS service.
2. An IAM administrator can view, but not edit the permissions for service-linked roles.

Service roles

1. A service role is a role that an AWS service assumes to perform actions on your behalf.
2. An IAM administrator can create, modify, and delete a service role from within IAM.

From the docs [Using service-linked roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html)

> Remember that service roles are different from service-linked roles. A service role is an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) that a service assumes to perform actions on your behalf. An IAM administrator can create, modify, and delete a service role from within IAM. For more information, see [Creating a role to delegate permissions to an AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html) in the IAM User Guide. A service-linked role is a type of service role that is linked to an AWS service. The service can assume the role to perform an action on your behalf. Service-linked roles appear in your AWS account and are owned by the service. An IAM administrator can view, but not edit the permissions for service-linked roles.

Comment: "A service role is a role that an AWS service assumes to perform actions on your behalf." I believe that also applies to service-linked roles, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75719677

Answer (score -1):

A key difference is that service-linked roles are pre-defined by AWS for a particular service, whereas a service-role is a user-defined IAM role which can be created, edited and deleted - and which IAM Policies can be attached to.

---

"A service-linked role is a unique type of IAM role that is linked directly to a service. Service-linked roles are predefined by the service and include all of the permissions that the service requires to call other AWS services on your behalf."

From Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html#using-service-linked-role?

Also see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html

Service role - see "Creating a role for an AWS service' here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html